# DRYest way to check if in the first iteration of an .each loop in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, each

In my `.erb`, I have a simple `each` loop:

```
<%= @user.settings.each do |s| %>
  ..
<% end %>
```

What is the simplest way to check if it's currently going through its first iteration? I know I could set `i=0...i++` but that is just too messy inside of an `.erb`. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal? Would it be easier to just do something with the first element, then iterate over the rest? It keeps the conditional logic out.

Comment: @DaveNewton that sounds like an interesting approach, you should post an example :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It depends on the size of your array. **If it is really huge** (couple of hundreds or more), you should [`.shift`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/shift) the first element of the array, treat it and then display the collection:

```
<% user_settings = @user_settings %>
<% first_setting = user_settings.shift %>
# do you stuff with the first element 
<%= user_settings.each do |s| %>
  # ...
```

Or you can use [`.each_with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index):

```
<%= @user.settings.each_with_index do |s, i| %>
  <% if i == 0 %>
    # first element
  <% end %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes! It's amazing how quickly you can forget things like this when you hardly use them. Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow made me wait 10 minutes before accepting the answer, no worries on that. And this code is for simply displaying the first item in the loop a little differently than the rest. I guess I could have separated them, but it seems like a loop would be easier and keep the group of code more contained. You hit the nail on the head

Answer (score 7):

The most readable way I find is following:

```
<%= @user.settings.each do |s| %>
  <% if @user.settings.first == s %>
    <% # Your desired stuff %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```